# In a 'div' element, how to align text to the left while aligning all other items to the right?

Tags: html, css, layout

It's like a post where the title appears on the left and the dropdown settings menu's arrow on the right..
This is what I have till now

```
<style>
    .thread {
        background-color: skyblue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 90%;
        align-self: center;
        text-align: end;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header {
        width: fit-content;
        display: inline-block;
        align-self: right;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .titletext {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
<div class="thread">
    <p class="titletext">Title</p>
    <div class="header"><img class="arrow" onclick="showPopover(this)" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/7/7584.png" /></div>
</div>
```

[It appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biSX1.png)

[And I'm trying to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PssMo.png)

Sorry if the code is too random or if some lines are unneeded but I've been searching and trying many stuff so that's what I have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float:right` on the arrow, and `text-align:left` on the entire header.

```css
.thread {
        background-color: skyblue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 90%;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header {
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 25px;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
        margin: 12px;
    }

    .titletext {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="thread">
    <p class="titletext">Title</p>
    <img class="arrow" onclick="showPopover(this)"
    src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/7/7584.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.titletext {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use   `float:left;`

```css
    .thread {
        background-color: skyblue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 90%;
        align-self: center;
        text-align: end;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header {
        width: fit-content;
        display: inline-block;
        align-self: right;
        padding:15px 10px;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .titletext {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
        float:left;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="thread">
    <p class="titletext">Title</p>
    <div class="header"><img class="arrow" width="20" onclick="showPopover(this)" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/7/7584.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put you´r `class="titletext"` like:

```
.titletext {
    position: absolute;
    top;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use float:left on the titletext

```
<style>
    .thread {
        background-color: skyblue;
        height: 50px;
        width: 90%;
        align-self: center;
        text-align: end;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 6px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .header {
        width: fit-content;
        display: inline-block;
        align-self: right;
    }

    .arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 50%;
    }

    .titletext {
        display: inline-block;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
<div class="thread">
    <p class="titletext">Title</p>
    <div class="header"><img class="arrow" onclick="showPopover(this)" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/7/7584.png" /></div>
</div>
```